# Combination of m elements from the first half of an ordered set

Tags: combinations

I have an ordered sequence with $n$ elements: $\{1,...,n\}$. I would like to obtain all the possible combinations of $m$ elements using just the first half of $n$ (so the numbers from $0$ to $n/2$). I feel that just ${\frac{n}{2}\choose m}$ does not return the fact that I want the first half of the set.

Comment: Why shouldn't it? Restrict your set to $\{1,..., \frac{n}{2} \}$ and forget about your initial set. Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Assuming $n$ is even?

Comment: Well, if n is not even I suppose GYBE for "the first half" intends $\frac{n-1}2$ or $\frac{n+1}2$